# PHP logical AND of two variables

Tags: php, logic

I'd like to do this:

`$var = ($var2 . $var3)`

This means `$var` is only true if `$var1` and `$var2` are truthy (anything that will cast to a boolean `true`).

Comment: Why aren't you just using the && operator?

Comment: @Reanimation - Due to the fact I lack the brainpower often associated with cognitive thought ability ;-P

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn all of [php's operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.` is the string concatenation operator.](http://php.net/language.operators.string) Use [`&&` for a boolean AND operation](http://php.net/language.operators.logical):

```
$var = $var2 && $var3;
```

Comment: Gah! So simple. Maybe I should have tried this first... Thanks Gumbo!

Answer (score 2):

Do it like this:

```
 $var = ($var2 && $var3);
```

or simply like SQL:

```
 $var = ($var2 and $var3);
```

Read more about [Logical Operators and how to use them](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) at PHP manual. Both `&&` and `and` operators are good enough for it, the only difference being the precedence.

Comment: In case anyone cares, the difference between "&&" and "and" is operator precedence.  The same is true with "||" and "or".  Same operation; different precedence.

Comment: Be aware that `&&` and `and` have a different operator precedence priority. In this case the parentheses are required to have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

> $var = isset( $var2 ) && isset( $var3
>   );

?